# How to modify a vector member's value?

Tags: c++, vector, operators

I was trying to use vector svec to store some string values. But when compiling at Dev C++ 5.6.1, the compiler reported an error of "no match for operator=". Why is there this error and how to fix it? Thanks.

```cpp
    #include<vector>
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
        vector<string> svec[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            svec[i] = "ABC";
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

[Error] no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::vector >' and 'const char [4]')

edit: The problem is in vector svec[100]; Things go well after changing it to vector svec(100);

edit2: I'm curious what the compiler regards this following declaration. Is svec still declared as a vector?

```cpp
vector<string> svec[100];
```

Comment: `svec` is a array of vectors. You need a size 100 vector, `vector<string> svec(100);`

Comment: I know this is probably just an example, but a tip: you can create a vector with the same element repeated like this: `vector<string> svec(100, "ABC");`

Comment: Yup the problem lies in the declaration. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`vector<string> svec[100];` is creating an array with 100 elements of `std::vector<std::string>`. That's valid syntax although it's a rather odd thing to do.

In its current form, `svec[i]` therefore refers to a `std::vector<std::string>`. Assigning "ABC" to that is not possible. That's why you get the error.

What you mean to write is `vector<string> svec(100);`. This is calling one of the `vector` *constructors* which pre-sizes the vector to have 100 elements.

It just happens that `std::vector` overloads the `[]` operator to give you element access. (A rather convenient analogue to pure arrays.) If you make the change, `svec[i]` will refer to a string which you can set in the way that you currently do.

Comment: Pleasure. Quite a long-winded explanation but does explain why you get the error "quite late" in compilation.

Answer (score 2):

Change this statement

```
vector<string> svec[100];
```

to

```
vector<string> svec( 100 );
```

That is instead of an array of 100 vectors you should define a vector of 100 elements.:)

Or you could write simply

```
    vector<string> svec;
    // svec.reserve( 100 );
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        svec.push_back( "ABC" );
    }
```

And the most simplest way is the following

```
int main() {
        vector<string> svec( 100, "ABC" );
        return 0;
    }
```